# Binding Activity with Service

Tags: android, service

i am trying to bind activity with service. I read this [tutorial](http://dharmendra4android.blogspot.in/2012/05/bind-service-using-ibinder-class.html). it is running but i am not getting what is need of `LocalBinder` class in Service. Why can not we create object of Service class directly for accessing public method of service.

Comment: Read this description about Android service: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: I suggest you read [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) first before heading to blogs.